# Hosting a Server using CloudBeans

Tags: java, sockets, ip, cloudbees, paas

I wanted to host a Server using CloudBees (with Sockets). So I just uploaded my Runnable Jar File. The problem is now, that I don't which IP address to use client side, and what about the port. I create a ServerSocket using `new ServerSocket(5000)`. What about this port? And what IP do I have to enter at `new Socket(IP, 5000)`? Or isn't this possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At CloudBees you will not able to get a fixed IP address unless you buy a dedicated server. Be aware that in the  multi-tenant option, your application could be deployed in different physical machines every time you deploy-redeploy your app. Only way to get the IP address where your application is working on is through the URL that your application uses (APPID.ACCOUNTID.cloudbees.net).

Regarding the port number, UDP/TCP non-http traffic can't be routed to your application by the front-end router.